# Magento 1.9.x: Custom attribute not show in filter Category

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I was set Is_Anchor = Yes

In Custom attribute, i set like this

[image]

It show when i search product, but it not show in category

Please help me

UPDATE QUESTION

[image]

Comment: can you share the full snap of the page?

Comment: Hi Nikul, please check update question